# Created zip file contain folder structure using tar command in PHP

Tags: php, command, filepath, naming

I am trying to create a zip of all files in abc folder with the name filename.zip using following command in php like:

```
exec(tar -cvf filename.zip /home/public_html/uploads/abc/)
```

but the created zip has the folder structure home/public_html/uploads. Please help me to get rid of these folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec("tar -cvf filename.zip -C /home/public_html/uploads/ abc/")`

Note the space before 'abc/'. The -C switch tells tar to first change directory to /home/public_html/uploads and then compress 'abc' folder.

You could also start the command from '/home/public_html/uploads' and specify the absolute path for the output file like

`chdir('/home/public_html')`

`exec("tar -cvf /full/path/to/filename.zip abc/")`

Comment: exec("tar -cvf filename.zip -C /home/public_html/uploads/ abc/") is not working for me then I use chdir('/home/public_html') exec("tar -cvf /full/path/to/filename.zip abc/")  now the folder abc is there how I can remove that also

Comment: then `chdir('/home/public_html/abs');` and then `exec("tar -cvf /full/path/to/filename.zip *")`

Comment: this is not working but I will do it with previous working one, thanks