# Remove folder structure (parents only) using ZIP command in PHP

Tags: php, linux, command, zip, exec

I want to create a zip of all files in `X` folder with the name filename.zip using following command in php like:

`exec(zip -r "./Zips/filename.zip" "./Uploads/Data/X/")`

but the created zip has the folder structure `Uploads/Data/X`. Please help me to get rid of these parent folders - `Uploads/Data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Ignoring folder structure when creating zip archive (Linux):**
>   
> By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).

Few approaches:

- moving to `X` folder beforehand:

  ```
  exec('cd /./Uploads/Data/X/; zip -r "./Zips/filename.zip" "*"');
  ```
- using `-j` (`--junk-paths`) option:

  ```
  exec('zip -j "./Zips/filename.zip" "./Uploads/Data/X/"');
  ```

Comment: Is there any solution like this, available? [Created zip file contain folder structure using tar command in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927356/created-zip-file-contain-folder-structure-using-tar-command-in-php)

Comment: @Phoenix, what do you mean?

Comment: Something like this: `exec("tar -cvf filename.zip -C /home/public_html/uploads/ abc/")`. So that you don't have to use the `cd` command before.

Comment: @Phoenix, it seems like `zip` command doesn't have such option like `-C` , it has `-b` option(creation of temporary archive with relocation) but it's a bit different.